# indexOfObject with Duplicate Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsarray

I have an NSArray of songs and would like to put them in a playlist. When I play the playlist I use `indexOfObject` to figure out the current songs index in the queue. I already overided `isEqual`, so to show that two media items were the same and would prefer not to hack at this method. I tried out NSOrderedSet instead of NSArray and it displayed each song once as opposed to how many instances of the same song are in it. Is their a class that mixes NSArray and NSOrderedSet so that each index is a unique object but there can be duplicate objects at different indexes?

Code:

```
- (PlayerItem *)nextSong{
        if(queue.count > 0){
            NSInteger songIndex = [queue indexOfObject:currentSong];
            NSLog(@"%ld in %lu", (long)songIndex, (unsigned long)queue.count);
            songIndex = songIndex + 1;
            if (songIndex < [queue  count]){
                return queue[songIndex];
            }else{
                return queue[0];
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

**Comment from Below:**

> I mean if I cycle threw songs than it can play Song 1 then 1 again
>   then 2 then 3 then 3 again. This isn't possible though because the
>   indexOfObject always returns the first duplicate object.

Comment: I don't really get what you want to achieve. Either objects are unique inside your data representation or not. I don't know how objects could be unique and at the same time have duplicates...

Comment: I mean if I cycle threw songs than it can play Song 1 then 1 again then 2 then 3 then 3 again. This isn't possible though because the indexOfObject always returns the first duplicate object.

Comment: Why are you using `indexOfObject` to access the songs in the playlist? Are you simply enumerating the contents of the playlist or something entirely different?

Comment: I'm enumerating it. I have a method that calls the next song by getting the index of the current song and adding one.

Comment: Why are you manually incrementing the index? If you're using enumeration, you'll have the index. If you're using fast enumeration, you'll have the song. Could you show us some code?

Comment: How aboutusing NSSet for that ?

Comment: They are not distinct objects and it wouldnt be in order.

Comment: Don't forget that if you re-define `isEqual:` you also _must_ re-define `hash`.

Comment: If the objects you're adding to `queue` are distinct, then `indexOfObject` will match a distinct object. One way would be to implement the `NSCopying` protocol in the `PlayerItem` class and store a _copy_ of each object in `queue`, i.e. `[queue addObject:[item copy]];` This will ensure that each object in the array will have a distinct pointer.

Comment: Just save the index of the song you're playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are finding out which song from the playlist is currently playing: You seem to store the `currentSong` in an ivar or so.

As it is possible that this song appears twice in the playlist it is just not enough information to know what's playing. Example:

"My playlist is A, A, B, C, C. Right now A is playing."

As you can see, from this information you can't know what's the next song.

A solution would be to store the index in the playlist or some other information to know the progress in the playlist.

Comment: Thats the route I ended up using but my only fear is that when going through playlists the index would not get reset and it would call an index that isn't feasible. I guess this just requires testing though. Thanks!